How change the value of specific positional variable in shell
I want to create a shell script that adds a string to the final positional variable.  (Specific use: script calls rsync, so I can call it with a destination directory, with the script auto-adding my login info)
I know that ${@: -1} references the final argument, but I can't find a way to change it, adding [LOGIN]@[HOST]:directory, where "directory" is my script's final arg.  Then the script only has to call rsync with $*

You can use set to set the positional arguments.
#!/bin/bash
final=${@: -1}                  # Get the last argument.
final=login@host:$final         # Modify it.
set -- "${@:1:$#-1}" "$final"   # Set the arguments back: from 1 to the last but 1,
                                # use the original values.
for arg in "$@" ; do
    printf '%s\n' "$arg"
done

Testing:
$ ./script.sh a b c
a
b
login@host:c


Looks great!  "${@:1:$#-1}" is the cryptic incantation I needed.  Thanks so much

@murspieg: Use accept/upvote to thank :-)

i tried to upvote, but don't have enuf rep points yet.  forgot about 'accept' - thanks for the reminder and esp thanks for the code!
